# Using itertools or zip to parse current value and next value in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Consider the file `eclip_bam_paths.txt`:

```
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample1Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample3Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample4Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample5Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample6Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample7Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample8Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

and the file `eclip_bais_paths.txt`:

```
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample1Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample3Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample4Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample5Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample6Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample7Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample8Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai
```

This code loops through both files but does not retrieve the next value in the loop:

```
keys = ['bam_rep_1','bai_rep_1','bam_rep_2','bai_rep_2']
l = []

with open('src/eclip_bam_paths.txt') as bams, open('src/eclip_bais_paths.txt') as bais:
    for bamline,bailine in zip(bams,bais):
        d = { keys[0]: bamline.strip(), keys[1]: bailine.strip() } 
        l.append(d)

import json
final_code = json.dumps(l)

with open('./output/eclip_array.json','w') as out:
    out.write(final_code)
```

I would like to have an iteration that grabs the next value in each file, for example the first iteration should look like this:

```
keys = ['bam_rep_1','bai_rep_1','bam_rep_2','bai_rep_2']
l = []

with open('src/eclip_bam_paths.txt') as bams, open('src/eclip_bais_paths.txt') as bais:
    for bamline,bailine in zip(bams,bais):
        d = { keys[0]: bamline.strip(), keys[1]: bailine.strip() , keys[2]: bamline.secondvalueinthefile , keys[3]: bailine.secondvalueinthefile } 
        l.append(d)

import json
final_code = json.dumps(l)
```

Is it possible to achieve that with `itertools` or buit-in python functions ?

Expected output of first iteration:

```
[{"bam_rep_1": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample1Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", "bai_rep_1": "/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample1Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai","bam_rep_2":"/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam","bai_rep_2":"/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai"},....]
```

P.S: I was wondering how I could implement this `itertools` function in my case:

```
import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not retrieve the next value in the loop*? what is the output and what is the expected output?

Comment: for the first iteration I mean this value `/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam` and this value `/groups/cgsd/alexandre/eclip/bam_inputs_akshay/10249_sample2Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bai` . I added the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readlines()` to get all the lines in the files and loop on the results with index with 2 interval

```
with open('src/eclip_bam_paths.txt') as bams, open('src/eclip_bais_paths.txt') as bais:
    all_lines = list(zip(bams.readlines(), bais.readlines()))
    for i in range(0, len(all_lines) - 1, 2):
        d = {keys[0]: all_lines[i][0].strip(), keys[1]: all_lines[i][1].strip(),
             keys[2]: all_lines[i + 1][0].strip(), keys[3]: all_lines[i + 1][1].strip()}
        l.append(d)
```

Another approach with `itertools.islice`:

```
def chunks(size, lists):
    while True:
        val = list(itertools.islice(lists, size))
        if not val:
            break
        yield val

with open('src/eclip_bam_paths.txt') as bams, open('src/eclip_bais_paths.txt') as bais:
    for group in chunks(2, zip(bams.readlines(), bais.readlines())):
        d = {keys[0]: group[0][0].strip(), keys[1]: group[0][1].strip(),
             keys[2]: group[1][0].strip(), keys[3]: group[1][1].strip()}
        l.append(d)
```

Comment: nice but I was really looking for an `itertools` approach.

Comment: @alex update my answer with `itertools` approach